# Invalid database name specified for backup or restore operation in when database path is long

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have a db with a long path:

```
C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Apps\\2.0\\ZV0DG5JM.3OH\\XQ31WEZB.OKA\\camman.exe_af50f6b9afda55f2_0001.0005_none_2c544a12b9bb2c09\\CameraManDB.mdf
```

I use the following code to backup:

```
public void BackupDatabase(string filePath, string DbPath)
{
    using (CameraManDBEntities dbEntities = new CameraManDBEntities())
    {
        string backupQuery = @"BACKUP DATABASE @DbPath TO DISK = N'{0}'";
        backupQuery = string.Format(backupQuery, filePath);

        dbEntities.Database.SqlQuery<object>(backupQuery, new SqlParameter("DbPath", DbPath)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

When I call the following method:

```
BackupDatabase(BackUpFileName, @"C:\Users\Mahmood\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZV0DG5JM.3OH\XQ31WEZB.OKA\camman.exe_af50f6b9afda55f2_0001.0005_none_2c544a12b9bb2c09" + "\\CameraManDB.mdf");
```

it throws this exception:

> Invalid database name 'C:\Users\Mahmood\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZV0DG5JM.3OH\XQ31WEZB.OKA\camman.exe_af50f6b9afda55f2_0001.0005_none_2c544a12b9bb2c09\CameraManDB.mdf' specified for backup or restore operation.\r\nBACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I think it's very simple but I couldn't find any obvious solution about long identifiers.

Thank you for guiding!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are passing the physical *path* of the database in parameter `@DbPath` but then using that parameter at the place in `BACKUP` where you specify the database *name*. This database obviously doesn't exist, hence the error.

You need to change it as follows:

```
public void BackupDatabase(string filePath, string dbName)
{
    using (CameraManDBEntities dbEntities = new CameraManDBEntities())
    {
        string backupQuery = @"BACKUP DATABASE @DbName TO DISK = N'{0}'";
        backupQuery = string.Format(backupQuery, filePath);

        dbEntities.Database.SqlQuery<object>(backupQuery,
            new SqlParameter("DbName", dbName)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

BackupDatabase(BackUpFileName, "CameraManDB");
```

I would also make the path a parameter instead of doing dynamic SQL, i.e.:

```
BACKUP DATABASE @DbName TO DISK = @FilePath
```

Comment: Oh so sorry! I forget to mention that i use sql localdb. It did not worked for me.